# How do i write this query using TypeORM's QueryBuilder?

Tags: mysql, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I ran this code directly on mySQL server and i'm getting the desired results, now how do i replicate this in my code using typeORM's queryBuilder?

```
SELECT user.id, user.email, user.image, user.phone_number, 
user.merchantLocationId, ugg.userGroupsId AS groupId, ug.description AS 
groupName, ur.id as roleId, ur.description AS role_name, ugr.priviledges
FROM ipay.user, ipay.user_user_group_user_groups AS ugg, 
ipay.user_group_roles AS ugr, ipay.user_groups AS ug, 
ipay.user_roles AS ur
WHERE user.id = ugg.userId AND ugg.userGroupsId = ugr.group_id AND 
ugr.role_id = ur.id AND user.email = "press@xyz.com";
```

Comment: What have you tried? It would be nice to see an attempt and some code as a starting point

Comment: I just went with the raw query. `getManger().query('select user.id..')`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to translate that sort of query into typeorm. The closest example I could give would be something like this

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(User) private readonly userRepository: Repository<User>) {}

  async findUserByEmail(email: string): Promise<User | null> {
    return await this.userRepository({
      relations: ['roles', 'groups'],
      where: {
        email,
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Where your UserEntity looks like this

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({
    unique: true,
  })
  email: string;

  @ManyToMany(type => Group, group => group.users)
  groups: Group[];

  @ManyToOne(type => Role, role => role.users)
  role: Role;
}
```

It's not an exact match but hopefully will give you some insight into how you can achieve your query.

Comment: Your approach would only work if role are independent of the groups. but this is definitely a step forward.

Comment: @OmarMohammed Sorry I should've added this http://typeorm.io/#/find-options There's an option key called join that would help with your query :)

Comment: Great, that helps build the exact query, thanks @sourRaspberri